# Loop through and subtract two columns in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a df that looks like this:

```
 Year Subscribers Forecast AbsError
1 2006    23188171        0        0
2 2007    28745769        0        0
3 2008    34880964        0        0
4 2009    46373266        0        0
```

I have a lop that fills in the forecast column and then it should subtract the subscriber value from the forecast value and put that number into the AbsError column, like so:

```
 Year   Subscribers    Forecast     AbsError
1 2006    23188171     9680000       13508171
2 2007    28745769     27960000      46240000
3 2008    3488096      46240000      11359036
```

My Loop looks like this: 
`for (i in 1:nrow(new.phone)) {
  new.phone$Forecast[i] <- ((1.828e+07 )*new.phone$Year[i]) + (-3.666e+10) 
  new.phone$AbsError <- abs((new.phone$Subscribers[i] - new.phone$Forecast[i]))
}`

Although this loop is giving the correct forecasted values, its giving the incorrect AbsError values, but i cannot figure out why. All the AbsError values are 10464033, but that is wrong. Any ideas why this is?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because you are assigning to `new.phone$AbsError` in each iteration of the loop rather than `new.phone$AbsError[i]`. You also might be interested in learning better ways to operate on data frames than writing your own loops. `dplyr` is a good place to start, but not the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)

k <- read.table(text = "Year Subscribers Forecast AbsError
1 2006    23188171        0        0
2 2007    28745769        0        0
3 2008    34880964        0        0
4 2009    46373266        0        0")

k%>%mutate(Forecast = ((1.828e+07 )*Year) + (-3.666e+10) )%>%
  mutate(AbsError = abs(Subscribers-Forecast))
```

Results:

```
Year Subscribers Forecast AbsError
1 2006    23188171  9680000 13508171
2 2007    28745769 27960000   785769
3 2008    34880964 46240000 11359036
4 2009    46373266 64520000 18146734
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a for loop to do that. This does what you need:

```
new.phone$Forecast <- ((1.828e+07) * new.phone$Year) + (-3.666e+10)
new.phone$AbsError <- abs(new.phone$Subscribers - new.phone$Forecast)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were just missing the index in the second line of the loop. Should be:   `new.phone$AbsError[i] <- [...]` not `new.phone$AbsError <- [...]`.

Anyway, you could skip the loop of you want:

```
new.phone$Forecast <- (1.828e+07) * new.phone$Year + (-3.666e+10) 
new.phone$AbsError  <- abs(new.phone$Subscribers - new.phone$Forecast)

new.phone
  Year Subscribers Forecast AbsError
1 2006    23188171  9680000 13508171
2 2007    28745769 27960000   785769
3 2008    34880964 46240000 11359036
4 2009    46373266 64520000 18146734
```